# How to Match on Joined Collections Using Laravel and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections "bookings" and "users". In "bookings" collection I have a field `"user"`. It is related to `"users._id"`.

I have a booking listing page. In this listing page data from "bookings" and "users" are showing.

In this listing page I have a text box to search `invoice_number, payment_type, txid and usrEmail`. I have written query to search `invoice_number, payment_type, txid` and it is working but I am stuck on `usrEmail` section. How can I combine with `users` and write search query to search `usrEmail`?

I am using laravel and mongodb. I am following "https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb"

**bookings**

`_id, user, invoice_number, payment_type, txid`

**users**

`_id, firstName, SecondName, usrEmail`

**Search Query**

```
$bookings = Booking::select('_id', 'invoice_number', 'temp_user_id', 'user', 'checkin_from', 'reserve_to', 'beds', 'dormitory', 'sleeps', 'status', 'payment_status', 'payment_type', 'total_prepayment_amount', 'cabinname', 'reference_no', 'clubmember', 'bookingdate', 'txid')
                ->where('is_delete', 0)
                ->where(function($query) use ($search) { /* That's the closure */
                    $query->where('invoice_number', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('payment_type', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('txid', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                })
                ->skip($start)
                ->take($limit)
                ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                ->get();
```

**App\Booking**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Userlist', 'user', '_id');
    }
```

**Images of two collection**
**User**
[image]
**Bookings**
[image]

**User collection**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57877d23049ac1b819000029"), "usrName" : "adminuser", "usrPassword" : "96a65063135247fef732b5901fe05d1f", "usrFirstname" : "Sarath", "usrLastname" : "TS", "usrTelephone" : null, "usrEmail" : "sara@gmail.com", "usrMobile" : "956209959", "usrAddress" : null, "usrFax" : "4564654", "usrZip" : null, "usrBirthday" : null, "usrDAV" : "316148-DAV-Deutscher Alpenverein", "usrActive" : "1", "usrlId" : "1", "lngId" : "1", "usrPasswordSalt" : ";:?hJM\"9=z/)ea?{%-[**:]68UOT>{gj^{P0+RCF#,Id8c:n+h", "usrRegistrationDate" : ISODate("2016-07-14T11:53:07Z"), "usrRegistrationToken" : "2c2e296bda1661c7fc0645f927d0b17f", "is_delete" : "0", "usrUpdateDate" : ISODate("2017-05-16T09:12:07Z"), "usrPasswordDate" : ISODate("2016-10-25T07:35:57Z"), "usrCity" : null, "usrNewsletter" : null, "money_balance" : "0", "usrCountry" : "Deutschland" }
```

**Booking Collection**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58046a49f8f888a80b00002a"), "cabinname" : "Matras-Haus", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-10-17T00:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2016-10-20T00:00:00Z"), "user" : "57877d23049ac1b819000029", "beds" : "2", "dormitory" : "1", "sleeps" : "3", "clubmember" : "1", "status" : "4", "comments" : "", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-10-17T06:06:01Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1), "payment_status" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58183678d2ae67a404431d5c"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-10-31T23:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2016-11-23T23:00:00Z"), "user" : "57877d23049ac1b819000029", "beds" : "2", "dormitory" : "0", "sleeps" : "2", "clubmember" : "0", "status" : "1", "total_price" : "1288", "payon_cabin" : "1288", "bed_prefer" : "0", "guests" : "2", "comments" : "", "prepayment_amount" : "0", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-01T06:30:16Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1), "payment_status" : "0" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("581b31f3d2ae674d5f431d5b"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-11-07T23:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2016-11-17T23:00:00Z"), "user" : "57877d23049ac1b819000029", "beds" : "3", "dormitory" : "0", "sleeps" : "3", "clubmember" : "0", "status" : "1", "total_price" : "840", "payon_cabin" : "840", "bed_prefer" : "0", "guests" : "3", "comments" : "", "prepayment_amount" : "0", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-03T12:47:47Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5821af65d2ae67c82154efc5"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-09-05T22:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2018-01-24T23:00:00Z"), "user" : "57877d23049ac1b819000029", "sleeps" : "2", "clubmember" : "0", "status" : "1", "total_price" : "5640", "payon_cabin" : "5630", "bed_prefer" : "0", "guests" : "2", "comments" : "", "prepayment_amount" : "21.25", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-08T10:56:37Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("582558d4d2ae679c4d8b4567"), "cabinname" : "2", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-07-31T22:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2017-08-02T22:00:00Z"), "user" : "57877d23049ac1b819000029", "beds" : "", "dormitory" : "", "sleeps" : "2", "clubmember" : "0", "status" : "", "total_price" : "80", "payon_cabin" : "60", "halfboard" : "", "bed_prefer" : "0", "guests" : "2", "prepayment_amount" : "20", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-11T05:36:20Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58352c3cd2ae672341ec89e1"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-05-31T22:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2017-06-02T22:00:00Z"), "user" : "57877d23049ac1b819000029", "beds" : "", "dormitory" : "", "sleeps" : "2", "clubmember" : "0", "status" : "", "total_price" : "80", "payon_cabin" : "60", "halfboard" : "", "bed_prefer" : "0", "guests" : "2", "prepayment_amount" : "20", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-23T05:42:20Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a `raw` query with `aggregate()` which can use the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operator to effect the "join" here:

```
  $result = Booking::raw(function($collection) use($search, $start, $limit) {
     return $collection->aggregate(array(
       array( '$lookup' => array(
         'from' => 'users',
         'localField' => 'user',
         'foreignField' => '_id',
         'as' => 'user'
       )),
       array( '$unwind' => array( 
         'path' => '$user', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => True
       )),
       array( '$match' => array(
         '$or' => array(
           array( 'invoice_number' => array( '$regex' => $search ) ),
           array( 'payment_type' => array( '$regex' => $search ) ),
           array( 'txid' => array( '$regex' => $search ) ),
           array( 'user.usrEmail' => array( '$regex' => $search ) )
         )
       )),
       array( '$skip' => $start ),
       array( '$limit' => $limit )
     ));
  });
```

The [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) will return an "array" for the target field containing "none" or more matching entries to the supplied `'localField'` value(s), where that is either singular or an array of values. Typically we use `ObjectId` here, especially when linking to the `'foreignField'` as `_id`.

This is better than anything that can be done client side, as any other operation would require making multiple queries to the database for each collection source. [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) does this in a single request and response.

The only real note is that because this is "separate" from the ORM/ODM, you need to specify the actual "collection name" and not that of the class or model. So I am just presuming `"users"` here, but you will maybe need to adjust that to what your collection for `Users` is actually called.

Anyhow, after you have the "joined" data then you can [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) on the `"usrEmail"` property from the joined data, and include in your query.

As for the actual query, since you are basically doing an `$or` condition across data from both collections we cannot really [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) until "after" the join is performed.

Then of course there are the aggregation stages for [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) for your pagination as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have added this but i am facing a problem "unknown top level operator: $user.usrEmail".

Comment: @samsam Typo. Sorry. Corrected. I do have your intention right? That you want a "regex" or SQL "Like" search across all these possible fields?

Comment: Thanks. At-present searching is not working for usrEmail. `'localField' => 'user', 'foreignField' => '_id'` localfield means `bookings.user` correct?

Comment: @samsam Yes. I did note that the presumption of "join" here relies on both the `"localField"` and the `"foreignField"` relating to each other **AND** they must contain the same data type. So if this is a 1:1 relation, then you need to have something stored in "bookings" that uses the value from `_id`. Or that is the presumption I am working on. If the `user` in booking actually refers to another "foreign" field other than `_id`, then point it there instead. All in the `$lookup` documentation, which is linked in the answer.

Comment: @samsam Show what you are doing in your question. Please include both the parent and related document for booking and user as viewed from the mongo shell. Please use the shell since that shows the correct data types assigned, that other dump forms often miss. Then I can clearly see what you have and advise.

Comment: @samsam I know what compass is. Can you please use the shell to connect and retrieve the "text" like I asked. I cannot copy and paste data from images. Can you please do that.

Comment: @samsam Also it may just be the compass interface, but it looks at a glance that the "user" field in booking is actually a string and not an `ObjectId`. If so then you cannot do a `$lookup` to join, and would need to fix the data types to be `ObjectId` values instead so the related `_id` values which are of `ObjectId` in the users collection can actually match. But again, please put the details and dumps and actual "mongo shell" output into your question. The comment thread here is already way too long.

Comment: @samsam You don't have a choice. There simply is no other way. The types do not match and you need them to in order to query. You also need to fix the code that is writing them as strings. It's a basic concept. `1 != "1"`. 10,000 is nothing. Takes me 2 seconds to update that many items.

Comment: Thank you so much.